# how I can contain mutable HashMap value in scala

Tags: scala, hashmap, set

I have a question about how to use hash maps in Scala.

My question is how to combine multiple values with the same key.

here is the data.

```
val mm = new HashMap[String, Set[String]] with MultiMap[String, String]

mm.addBinding("1","D1")
mm.addBinding("1","D2")
mm.addBinding("1","D7")
mm.addBinding("2","D2")
mm.addBinding("2","D3")
mm.addBinding("2","D4")
mm.addBinding("3","D4")
mm.addBinding("4","D5")
mm.addBinding("5","D6")
```

result :

```
key: 2, value: Set(D2, D3, D4)
key: 5, value: Set(D6)
key: 1, value: Set(D1, D2, D7)
key: 4, value: Set(D5)
key: 3, value: Set(D4)
```

I want get result like this.

```
key: 2, value: Set(D2, D3, D4, D1, D7)
key: 5, value: Set(D6)
key: 4, value: Set(D5)
```

because Key 2, Key 1 , K 3 have the same value (= D2) (= D4)
If you have the same value, you want to combine.

The KEY value does not matter. I want to make one set if even one value overlaps.

SO. This is ok too

```
key: 1, value: Set(D2, D3, D4, D1, D7)
key: 5, value: Set(D6)
key: 4, value: Set(D5)
```

OR

```
key: 3, value: Set(D2, D3, D4, D1, D7)
key: 5, value: Set(D6)
key: 4, value: Set(D5)
```

Comment: How do you choose which key has to stay. Why do you remove 1 and leave 2?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you leave either one. so remove 2 and leave 1 also OK. 
But the value is the same  ((( key: 1, value: Set(D2, D3, D4, D1, D7)  key:5 ~~~ )))

Comment: It is really not clear what the rules are here. 2 and 3 both have D4 so why don't they get folded together as well?

Comment: It was my mistake. :-(  I just fixed my question,

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to perform some additional processing with the `mm` map. See code below:

```scala
import scala.collection.mutable._

val mm = new HashMap[String, Set[String]] with MultiMap[String, String]

mm.addBinding("1","D1")
mm.addBinding("1","D2")
mm.addBinding("1","D7")
mm.addBinding("2","D2")
mm.addBinding("2","D3")
mm.addBinding("2","D4")
mm.addBinding("3","D4")
mm.addBinding("4","D5")
mm.addBinding("5","D6")

var nn = new HashMap[Set[String], Set[String]]
mm.map { case (k, vs) =>
  nn.find(_._2.intersect(vs).nonEmpty).fold {
    // No overlap
    nn = nn.addOne(Set(k) -> vs)
  } { case (ks, vss) =>
    // Find overlap, merging the keys and values
    nn = nn.subtractOne(ks).addOne(ks.union(Set(k)) -> vs.union(vss))
  }
}
nn // HashMap(HashSet(4) -> HashSet(D5), HashSet(5) -> HashSet(D6), HashSet(1, 2, 3) -> HashSet(D4, D7, D1, D2, D3))

// If you want the key to be just one value
val ll = nn.map { case (ks, vs) =>
  ks.head -> vs
}
ll // HashMap(1 -> HashSet(D4, D7, D1, D2, D3), 4 -> HashSet(D5), 5 -> HashSet(D6))
```

Playground example: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/W8fx8uIbStyoxEveOi89GA

Comment: Thanks. but I got build errors. " overloaded method value ++ with alternatives: (xs: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[String])scala.collection.mutable.Set[String] <and> [B >: String, That](that: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B])(implicit bf: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[scala.collection.mutable.Set[String],B,That])That cannot be applied to (Any) "

Comment: What's your scala version?

Comment: I've updated my answer to not use the ++ method. Not sure why it's a problem for you, but it should be good now.